# How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?

Tags: ssh, shell-script, zsh

I want to detect from a shell script (more specifically .zshrc) if it is controlled through SSH. I tried the HOST variable but it's always the name of the computer which is running the shell. Can I access the hostname where the SSH session is coming from? Comparing the two would solve my problem.

Every time I log in there is a message stating the last login time and host:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 18 23:07:28 CET 2011 from max on pts/1
Last login: Fri Mar 18 23:11:56 2011 from max
```

This means the server has this information.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Here are the criteria I use in my `~/.profile`:

- If one of the variables `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH_TTY` is defined, it's an ssh session.
- If the login shell's parent process name is `sshd`, it's an ssh session.

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
  SESSION_TYPE=remote/ssh
# many other tests omitted
else
  case $(ps -o comm= -p "$PPID") in
    sshd|*/sshd) SESSION_TYPE=remote/ssh;;
  esac
fi
```

(Why would you want to test this in your shell configuration rather than your session startup?)

Comment: Worked great thanks! https://github.com/balupton/dotfiles/commit/70c6dae9d489810d27d3ee551548d5ca2badb286

Comment: you might want to do this in your shell configuration if you want to enable ssh agent forwarding from your remote shell (since the environment vars need to be set in each shell you want to forward from) unless i'm missing something?

Comment: @underrun I don't understand your point. If you run another shell in the same session, it inherits the environment variables set by `.profile`. And what does this have to do with agent forwarding?

Comment: @Gilles if i want to us agent forwarding from a machine i'm ssh'd into already i will want to `eval $(ssh-agent)` but only if i've connected over ssh. i need both the ssh-agent process and the env vars right?

Comment: @underrun If you want to test for the presence of SSH agent forwarding, test for the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable. But why would you run an SSH agent in that case? Did you mean start an agent if you're logged in without agent forwarding? Why not start an agent if there isn't already one (`[ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || eval $(ssh-agent)`)?

Comment: @Gilles - doh! yes. that is much better. that works whether i log in locally (and my window manager sets it up) or if i ssh in and i have to start my own agent. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you add a brief explanation of why you recommend both tests? When should we expect `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_TTY` to be set but for the parent process to not be sshd and vice-versa?

Comment: @Praxeolitic The `SSH_*` variables are also set in subprocesses of a shell that's at the head of an SSH session, for example if you start a screen session over SSH (you should unset the variables before starting the session if you care). I think the reason for testing the parent process is that I started doing that before sshd defined any environment variables.

Comment: Actually, it would be great to see the "many other tests omitted"; would you be willing to share how you determine the session type in your profile?

Answer (score 29):

You should be able to check via the `SSH_TTY`, `SSH_CONNECTION`, or `SSH_CLIENT` variables.

Comment: Also add these to `env_keep` in `sudoers` to make it work across `su` commands:)

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same problem in Linux, using Bash. I first used the environment variable SSH_CONNECTION, but then realized that it is not set if you `su -`.

The lastlog solution above didn't work either after `su` or `su -`.

Finally, I am using `who am i`, which shows the remote IP (or the hostname) at the end if it's an SSH connection. It also works after su.

Using Bash regular expressions, this works:

```
if [[ $(who am i) =~ \([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\)$ ]] ; then echo SSH; else echo no; fi
```

If zsh doesn't support regular expressions, the same can be achieved in many different ways with grep, cut, sed, or whatever.

For the curious, below is what I use this for, in root's .bashrc :

```
    # We don't allow root login over ssh.
    # To enable root X forwarding if we are logged in over SSH, 
    # use the .Xauthority file of the user who did su

    w=$(who am i)
    if [[ $w =~ \([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\)$ ]] ; then
        olduser=${w/ .*/}
        oldhome=$(getent passwd $olduser | cut -d: -f 6)
        [ -f "$oldhome/.Xauthority" ] \
          && export XAUTHORITY=$oldhome/.Xauthority
    fi
```

An alternative which also works with `su` would be to recursively search for `sshd` through the parent processes:

```
#!/bin/bash

function is_ssh() {
  p=${1:-$PPID}
  read pid name x ppid y < <( cat /proc/$p/stat )
  # or: read pid name ppid < <(ps -o pid= -o comm= -o ppid= -p $p) 
  [[ "$name" =~ sshd ]] && { echo "Is SSH : $pid $name"; return 0; }
  [ "$ppid" -le 1 ]     && { echo "Adam is $pid $name";  return 1; }
  is_ssh $ppid
}

is_ssh $PPID
exit $?
```

If the function is added to .bashrc, it can be used as `if is_ssh; then ...`

Comment: doesn’t work in remote `tmux` sessions and also has issues if logged in via IPv6 and no DNS reverse name exists.

Comment: @bene: what doesn't work? The regular expression, or does `who am i` not show your IPv6 address?

Comment: 1) `who am i` doesn’t return anything in a remote `tmux` session. 2) IPv6 address might contain colons which your regex doesn’t allow. This might be tricky since `who am i` contains `(:0.0)` in X sessions for me (xterm).

Comment: @bene: The alternative solution which I just added should also work with IPv6. I don't know about tmux, but it does also work in `screen`.

Comment: I found it's easier to test with `[[ $(pstree -s $$) = *sshd* ]]` if the parent is a SSH connection. See [here for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270719/is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-connection-is-local-or-via-ssh-after-elevating-to).

Answer (score 10):

I think Gilles and Cakemox's answers are good, but just for completeness...

```
Last login: Fri Mar 18 23:07:28 CET 2011 from max on pts/1
```

comes from `pam_lastlog`<sup>1</sup>.

You can print `pam_lastlog` information using the `lastlog`<sup>2</sup> command, e.g.

```
$ lastlog -u mikel  
Username         Port     From             Latest
mikel            tty1                      Fri Jan 28 10:58:10 +1100 2011
```

for a local login, compared to

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
mikel            pts/9    mikel-laptop     Sat Mar 19 11:11:58 +1100 2011
```

for an SSH login.

On my system, this works to extract it

```
$ lastlog -u mikel | sed -ne '2{p;q}' | cut -c 27-42
mikel-laptop
```

`last` and `w` could be helpful too, for example

```
$ TTY=$(tty)
$ last -n 1 ${TTY#/dev/} | sed -ne '1{p;q}'
mikel    pts/12       :0.0             Sat Mar 19 11:29   still logged in
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Linux](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_lastlog.html)/[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pam_lastlog) documentation for `pam_lastlog`.
<sup>2</sup> [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lastlog.8.html)/[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lastlogin&sektion=8) `lastlog(8)` man pages.

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at your environment and finding the right option

```
printenv|grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.xxx
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.xxx
SSH_TTY=/dev/ttys021
```

You could hook into many of these environment variables to trigger specific actions based on their presence.

Answer (score 1):

On `systemd`, for a given session ID stored in the `session_id` variable, it is possible to query whether the session is remote or not using

```
loginctl show-session --value -p Remote "$session_id"
```

This will either print `yes` or `no`. It is also possible to query the service that started the sessions using

```
loginctl show-session --value -p Service "$session_id"
```

This will print `sshd` for SSH sessions and something else otherwise.

On newer systems, `-P` can be used to abbreviate `--value -p`.

To correctly set the `session_id` variable, one can use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966477/5613485). This results in the following one-liners:

```
user@remotehost:~ $ loginctl session-status | (read session_id ignored; loginctl show-session --value -p Remote "$session_id")
yes
user@remotehost:~ $ loginctl session-status | (read session_id ignored; loginctl show-session --value -p Service "$session_id")
sshd
```

```
user@localhost:~ $ loginctl session-status | (read session_id ignored; loginctl show-session --value -p Remote "$session_id")
no
user@localhost:~ $ loginctl session-status | (read session_id ignored; loginctl show-session --value -p Service "$session_id")
lightdm
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `pstree` to find any `sshd` parent

Using `sudo su` and certain other commands make a lot of solutions require some complexity to work under all conditions.  A simple solution to this is to walk the process tree up to the init process and check for any parents that are `sshd`.  The easiest way to do that is with `pstree`:

```
if pstree -s -p $$ | grep -c '\-sshd(' >/dev/null; then
    echo "SSH session"
else
    echo "regular session"
fi
```

Explanation:

1. The `$$` gives the currently running process PID
2. `pstree -s -p $$` creates a single line listing of the process tree
3. The output of pstree is then piped to grep
4. `grep '\-sshd(' >/dev/null` checks for the sshd process, since the process name will always have a dash before it and a parenthesis after it (it will not be fooled by a parent that *contains* sshd). For example:

   ```
   systemd(1)───sshd(1054)───sshd(709709)───sshd(709800)───bash(709801)───bash(710790)───pstree(711090)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This checks the oposite:

```
$ ps -o comm= -p $PPID
login
$
```

That's definitely terminal on the computer, not SSH

Answer (score -1):

This is to check all established connection from other user using SSH

```
netstat | grep ssh
```

Comment: This is not at all reliable.