# How to read bash config when working with SSH remote sessions

Tags: ssh, tmux, bashrc, node.js

I have a Node.js app which I want to deploy on my VM machine. Before starting the app, I want to set few commands which should be read before the app is started.

I placed those commands inside `.bashrc` just similar to what I have done on my local environment.

Sample Command in `.bashrc`

```
export TOY_DIR=~/work/git/toyPlayer
export TOY_PLAYER_ENV=dev
```

Now, when I am running my app with `node app.js`. It is throwing me an error that environment not found. However this thing works perfectly on my localbox.

After some google search, I tried this command

```
tmux
node app.js
```

It started node server fine but now I am not able to exit from tmux shell. I used CTRL+C to exit but it stopped the node server.

PS: I know I can do remote login to it and work. But I am trying to learn doing things with command line.

What is the best practice to achieve this ?

**PPS**: I do not want to detect if the shell is controlled from SSH. I want to export some variables before starting my Node app. These variables are environment variables which are read by a config.js present inside my app.

Here is an example, How am I using the environment variables.

```
var env = process.env['TOY_PLAYER_ENV']
```

My question is How to set these variables on my remote machine ?

Comment: If you want to keep it running, instead CTRL+C use CTRL+Z, after that a line will show the number of the job that has been put to sleep. Run `bg %theNumberYouGot` and it will keep running in the background.

Comment: @YoMismo Thanks I will try this..This would be very simple solution if it works for me..

Comment: @YoMismo No On Even pressing CTRL+Z it stopped my node server instance..

Comment: are you sure? did you check the jobs? did you run the `bg` command?

Comment: @YoMismo Yes, No command runs since my node server is running. I am not able to check the jobs and nor able to run bg command. CTRL+Z stops the node server.

Comment: CTRL+Z should take your process to a sleep state, It may seem that your node stopped but it didn't, it just went to sleep. If you are able to press CTRL+Z you should able to check the jobs, `jobs` command will show you those that are sleeping/running/... You will also be able to run `bg` command which will allow you to wake up a process (the node in this case) and keep it running in the background.

Comment: @YoMismo Thanks..You were right...It do not stop the node app. It just shows a message like this `[1] stopped node app.js` but it keeps on running. Thanks a lot for the help..Please put this as an answer and I will be happy to accept with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a very similar question with a good accepted answer: [How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh)

You can either check if one of the bash variables `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH_TTY` is set by checking if their length is not zero:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
    # do your stuff here
fi
```

Alternatively you can check if the shells parent process is named `sshd` by:

```
if [ $(ps -o comm= -p $PPID) = 'sshd' ]; then
    # do your stuff here
fi
```