# How to automatically load tmux at login, but not if already inside tmux?

Tags: bash, tmux, profile

I recently started using `tmux`. I found I can attach-or-create a tmux session by using:

```
tmux new-session -A -s main
```

I was hoping to put this into `.profile` so that I automatically get put into tmux when I connect via SSH. I'd like to skip this when logging on locally.

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh) which looks promising, however I'm concerned that if I launch tmux from `.profile` it'll then launch my shell and create another tmux ad infinitum!

So what's the correct way to avoid launching `tmux` from `.profile` if it's already running in tmux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tmux` sets the `$TMUX` variable to point to the socket, so you can do something like

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]
then
  ....
fi
```

The stuff inside the test will only be run if the variable is not set - ie you're not already inside a `tmux` session.

Comment: Spot on - I dared to try this and got `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`. Thanks!